# Can I create a bitcoin wallet with SecurityDriven.Net/Inferno library?

Tags: .net, public-key-encryption, bitcoin, .net-security

I see that [SecurityDriven.NET/Inferno](http://securitydriven.net/inferno/) is a minimalistic & safe approach to cryptography in .NET, especially compared to BouncyCastle.

Does it provide enough algorithms to create a simple bitcoin wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Base58 encoder/decoder is not in [Inferno](http://SecurityDriven.NET/inferno/). More importantly, Inferno uses NIST P-384 elliptic curve, while bitcoin uses Secp256k1 elliptic curve.

Comment: would you be willing to accept pull requests for this?

Comment: I guess that silence tells me the answer :)